Specral projection of Schrödinger operator
I'm reading the paper "Operators with singular continuous spectrum Ⅳ" (direct link) and I'm confused by a formula on page 26 regarding the spectral projection: $$P_{\{E\}}=\underset{T \to \infty}{\text{s-lim}} \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}e^{iEs}e^{-iHs}ds$$
My questions are:

How does one prove this?
Does this formula have a unitary analogue?

Thanks for any comments!
